# Multipl matrix in cell

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

I have a matrix `A=[1,2,3]` and a cell `B={[1,2,3],[1,2,5],[1,2,6]}`.
I would like the product of the matrix elements of a similar cell
that's mean  `A * B ={1*[1,2,3],2*[1,2,5],3*[1,2,6]};`
Without loop in matlab

Comment: Does the number of elements in `B` change? For instance does `A.*cell2mat(B)` gives what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Here a few ways to multiply as you described:

```
% inputs
A = [1,2,3];
B = {[1,2,3],[1,2,5],[1,2,6]};
```

using for-loop:

```
C1 = cell(size(B));
for i=1:numel(C1)
    C1{i} = A(i) * B{i};
end
```

using `cellfun`:

```
C2 = cellfun(@(a,b)a*b, num2cell(A), B, 'Uniform',false);
```

using `bsxfun`:

```
C3 = bsxfun(@times, A(:), cat(1,B{:}));
C3 = num2cell(C3,2)';
```

All results should be equal (output being a cell array):

```
assert(isequal(C1,C2,C3))
```

If I were to choose, I would stick with the for-loop. In this case it's likely faster and easiest to read.